# python-if a line and a next line starts with a specific string then print 0 in between them

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file which look like this:

```
line1
1
2
line2
line3
1
2
line4
1
2
line5
line6
```

If a line and the next line starts with the string `line` then it should 
 print `0` in-between the lines.

So the output should look like this:

```
line1
1
2
line2
0
0
line3
1
2
line4
1
2
line5
0
0
line6
```

Comment: Can you give a better description of the file or even better an example with several lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the file looks like:

```
line1
1
2
line2
line3
1
2
line4
...
```

If you would like to add two new lines with '0' between them you should do:

```
with open("your_file.txt") as txt_file:
    lines = txt_file.readlines()
prev_starts_with_line = False
for line in lines:
    if line.find("line") == 0:
        if prev_starts_with_line:
            print "0\n0"
        prev_starts_with_line = True
    else:
        prev_starts_with_line = False
    print line.strip()
```

the output would be:

```
line1
1
2
line2
0
0
line3
1
2
line4
```

Comment: Thanq soo much code is working :)